# Dual Boot Issues Arising from BIOS SATA Operation Change and SSD Addition

Tags: dual-boot, raid

Initially, I had a dual boot configuration of Windows and Ubuntu on my Dell machine. Upon installing an additional SSD, the SSD was not detected in Ubuntu, although it functioned properly in Windows.

In an attempt to address this, I changed the BIOS setting from AHCI to RAID ON after consulting online resources. This modification allowed the SSD to be recognized in Ubuntu, but it resulted in Windows failing to boot.

Further complicating matters, I made adjustments to Windows settings based on online suggestions. Unfortunately, these changes led to Windows not booting under either SATA operation setting (AHCI or RAID ON).

I am seeking assistance to understand the root cause of this issue and to determine a solution. I aim to re-establish the dual boot functionality of both operating systems while ensuring the safety of my data throughout the recovery process. Your guidance on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.